Concatenate imported data from PDF file, that was split into multiple rows, into one row
I imported data from a PDF file into Excel.
Some of the columns have been split into two rows.
This image shows the issue and the outcome I would like.

There are over 1000 rows. (Note that some rows do not need to be modified such as Contract 3.)
I was thinking of VBA code that would check if the row below in Column A is blank/null. If true, then it would concatenate the rows in Columns B and C.

what was the format of the original pdf and how did you import it into excel? may be it's easier to fix at that step

I used the "Get Data -> From PDF" function in excel. It looked fine in the PDF file, but I guess like K J mentioned, PDF doesn't have any concept of cells. Someone posted a solution, but I appreciate the discussion!

Here's one way to do it.  Select the data (excluding the headers) and run this:
Sub ConsolidateRows()
    Dim rw As Range, data As Range, r As Long, rwDest As Range, col As Long, v
    
    Set data = Selection
    For r = data.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        Set rw = data.Rows(r)
        If Len(rw.Cells(1).Value) = 0 Then ' "extra row" has no id in first cell
            'find next row above with a value in first cell
            Set rwDest = rw.Cells(1).End(xlUp).Resize(1, data.Columns.Count)
            If rwDest.Row < data.Rows(1).Row Then Exit Sub 'out of the data
            
            'copy values up and append to destination row
            For col = 2 To data.Columns.Count
                v = rw.Cells(col).Value
                If Len(v) > 0 Then 'anything to copy?
                    With rwDest.Cells(col)
                        .Value = .Value & IIf(.Value <> "", " ", "") & v
                    End With
                End If
            Next col
            rw.Delete 'remove this row
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

